# Countdown does not work after using the PHP time string into javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am creating time that i will use to make a countdown timer later. Its easy to create when only `JavaScript` or `jQuery` is my choice. But the problem comes when i get the `PHP` date time string and display it using `jQuery`. It does not dynamically update the time after using the `PHP` date and time string. Below is a little code of mine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var value = $("#date_time").text();

        function countdown(){
              setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
              var date = new Date(Date.parse(value));
              $("#php_date_time").text(date);

           }
        countdown();


    });



    </script>
</head>
<body >
    <div id="date_time"><?php echo Date("d-m-Y H:i:s");?></div>
    <div id="php_date_time"> </div>

</body>
</html>
```

The code works perfectly fine if i do not pass `PHP` date time string to `javascript Date()` function as an argument. If starts working, i can make countdown myself.

```
var date = new Date(); // works fine without passing php date time string
var date = new Date(Date.parse(value)); // this does not work fine. Time does not update
```

Please help suggest what i need to do.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use setInterval instead of setCountdown? Right after your function definition, use setInterval(countdown, 1000) and remove the setTimeout() inside of your function!

Comment: Seems to be working for me: http://codepad.viper-7.com/apEEgQ

Comment: What are you expecting? As @APAD1 showed, this code correctly takes the time from PHP and repeatedly displays it on the screen

Comment: @APAD1 actually its not. It suppose to update the time every second. But its not. I checked your link. I want it to update the time every second. The `PHP` time string is used to just tell `javascript` to start time from here.

Comment: @Shai its not repeatedly updating the minutes and seconds.

Comment: @Rebbeca you haven't written any code to update the minutes and seconds. The reason it worked without the PHP was that `new Date()` was getting a new "starting date" every second.

Comment: You are just echoing the date, that's not going to give you a live update of the minutes/seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want it to start from time that PHP gives you you need to change your javascript to use that time to set initial value and then change that each second. Now you're just updating with same value.

http://codepad.viper-7.com/sPVlEI

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var value = $("#date_time").text();   //get init value
    var date = new Date(Date.parse(value)); //store initial time

    setInterval(function countdown(){
        $("#php_date_time").text(date);    //set time
        date = new Date(date.getTime() + 1000);  //create new time from old + 1 sec
    },1000); // will call countdown() function every second

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is as the server compiles your php date just once, your `countdown` function always uses the same date value. there is another issue that you have to consider which is your server time doesn't necessary match with client time. you'd better start your timer with client time. but if you want to start it based on your server time, try this and your problem is solved:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var value = $("#date_time").text();

    function countdown(date){
        setTimeout(function(){
            countdown(new Date(date.valueOf()+1000));
        }, 1000);

        $("#php_date_time").text(date);
    }

    countdown(new Date(Date.parse(value)));
});
```

Comment: The problem is, everything is managed on the website according to the server time. As far as the countdown timer is concerned, i has to start from given time string.

Comment: I just want to do is to start the timer using javascript but the starting time is always be the php string.

Comment: I have just edited my answer I think this is exactly what you want and this is your jsfiddle [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mehranhatami/xJLbv/1/)

Comment: In this jsfiddle [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mehranhatami/xJLbv/1/) I have used a sample php date output, instead of `<?php echo Date("d-m-Y H:i:s");?>`

Comment: Actually, @Jeribo gave me the clue to achieve what i was looking for. The code snippet he provided about is working perfectly fine. Your JSFiddle demo is not what i was looking for. Your demo does not updates the time every second.

Comment: ok then as you see the only problem your code has was not changing the value of date, actually the @Jeribo 's clue is exactly what I have added to your code, which is growing your date value using `date.valueOf()+1000`. I don't know why this code doesn't update for you, actually it works perfectly for me, check this [example in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mehranhatami/xJLbv/1/).